# Download file using PowerShell commandlet

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, webclient, powershell-3.0

The command is working fine with [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012) (PowerShell 4.0), but it is not working with Windows 8 (PowerShell 4.0) for the same.

I want to download a file from an [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) server.

```
 (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://server12/vdir/v.exe','C:\pqr.exe')
```

I  tried this. It worked fine for me on Windows Server 2012, but on Windows 8 it gave me a method invocation error:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: You should inspect the inner exception in PowerShell using a try/catch (see [here](http://tasteofpowershell.blogspot.com/2011/10/innerexception-we-have-to-go-deeper.html)). I suspect the problem is that you don't have permission to write to the root folder on the Windows 8 machine unless you run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Windows 7 (32 bits), and I got the same error like you, so, I wrote a [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) script that generates a PowerShell script in order to download this file in the temporary folder and execute it, and it works fine for me.

**DownloadPSVBS.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
Dim URL,Ws,ByPassPSFile,PSFile,MyCmd,Result
URL = "http://hackoo.alwaysdata.net/Matrix.mp3"
Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
ByPassPSFile = "PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass -noprofile -file "
MyCmd = "$source = " & DblQuote(URL) & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$Filename = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($source)" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$dest = " & DblQuote("$env:temp\$Filename") & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "$wc.DownloadFile($source,$dest)" & VbCrlF
MyCmd = MyCmd & "Start-Process $dest"
Call WriteMyPSFile(MyCmd)
Result = Ws.run(ByPassPSFile & PSFile,0,True)
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub WriteMyPSFile(strText)
Dim fs,ts,PSFile
Const ForWriting = 2
    PSFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName, InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, ".")) & "ps1"
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(PSFile,ForWriting,True)
    ts.WriteLine strText
    ts.Close
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

For downloading a file with PowerShell you can use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx):

```
mkdir c:\download
Invoke-WebRequest http://server12/vdir/v.exe -OutFile c:\download\pqr.exe
```

Or use it like this:

```
mkdir C:\download
$a = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$a.DownloadFile("http://server12/vdir/v.exe","c:\download\pqr.exe")
```

Comment: "invoke-webrequest" takes much more time comparatively, and about other way..its working in server 2012 but not in windows 8. tried exact same way u suggested.

Comment: maby in win8 you don't have root access to write file make directory like download then second parameter must be "c:\download\pqr.exe" just test it

Comment: how to track $a.DownloadFile().. i mean how to check if download is complete or not through powershell. or does $a.downloadfile() returns any value..??